# Make thread pool block when max threads are in use?

Tags: python, threadpool

I am trying to make a thread pool that will block when the maximum number of threads are reached before adding another thread to the thread pool.

```
import thread_pool
import time

def slow_greeting(msg):
    time.sleep(5)
    print("Hello there {}".format(msg))

def main():
    tp = thread_pool.ThreadPool(3)
    while True:
        print("Top of the loop")
        tp.add_task(slow_greeting, 'a')
        tp.add_task(slow_greeting, 'b')
        tp.add_task(slow_greeting, 'c')

        # Should block here, waiting for a free thread
        tp.add_task(slow_greeting, 'd')
        tp.add_task(slow_greeting, 'e')
```

When this is run, however, "Top of the loop" is printed over and over again, while `slow_greeting` runs when it does.

How can I make a thread pool block when trying to add a task until there is at least one available thread for the task to run?

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is or why you would like to accomplish this. Your code does exactly what it's supposed to do. "Top of the loop" is printed but that does not mean that antother task is added to the pool. What actually happens (afaik) is the loop is running over and over again without a task being added until the pool has "a place" for a new task. The print statement is executed because there's no condition saying only print if there's space in the pool.

Comment: I would like to add a statement like `sleep_until_has_spot(tp)`. I would like to do this while I am requesting the same RESTful web service repeatedly (the response is sent to a callback function.) I do not want to make another connection until at least one of the first few has completed, along with associated processing.

Comment: I don't know if thread_pool has this but usually with threading and queue there is some kind of signaling that use can use to check for stuff like this.

Comment: This example does not involve a pool but you can see how a queue can be used to achieve what you want http://www.lonelycode.com/2011/02/04/python-threading-and-queues-and-why-its-awesome/